# Proof of Supporting Hyperplane Theorem from basic definitions.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

My purposes in posting this question are twofold. First, I would like to have a lemma which I have proven on the way to proving the Supporting Hyperplane Theorem checked for rigor (zero tolerance for assumptions please). The second is to get some kind of hint (a *hint* not a complete strategy!) as to how to proceed from where I am. I wish to prove this theorem from the definitions which I will list below, drawing on no other theorems from topology but allowing the use of certain basic theorems of linear algebra and geometry. Rigor is of paramount importance. Please find below the statement of the Supporting Hyperplane Theorem in the form which I'd like to prove it and the relevant definitions, along with the lemma which I mentioned.

$\underline{\text{Definitions:}}$

Convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ - If $E$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, $E$ is convex if and only if for all $\textbf{x}$ and $\textbf{y}$ in $E$, $\big(\textbf{x}+t(\textbf{y}-\textbf{x})\big)\in E$ when $0<t<1$.

Boundary of a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ - if $W$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, $\partial W$, the boundary of $W$, is the unique subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that for all open balls centered at $\textbf{x} \in W$ and of radius $r>0$, (denoted henceforth as $B_{r}(\textbf{x})$), $B_{r}(\textbf{x}) \cap E \neq \emptyset$ and $ B_{r}(\textbf{x}) \cap (\mathbb{R}^n-\{E\}) \neq \emptyset$.

Interior of a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ - If $W$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $int(E)$, the interior of $E$, is the set of all points such that there exists an open ball of radius $r>0$ such that said ball is a subset of $W$.

Hyperplane - $\{\textbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n \, |\,  c+\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_ix_i=0\}$ for some $c \in \mathbb{R}$ and some $\{a_i\}\in \mathbb{R}$.

$\underline{\text{Proposition:}}$

Let $E$ be a convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\textbf{p} \in \partial E$. Then there must exist a hyperplane, $H$, such that $E \cap H\subset\partial E$.

We note first that, owing to the fact that lines are preserved under translation, we may, without loss of generality, consider the instance where $\textbf{p}=\textbf{0}$.

$\textbf{Lemma}$:

For every closed ball of radius $r>0$, centered at the origin (henceforth $B_r(\textbf{0})$), there exist two subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$, $M$ and $N$, such that

1) $M \subset E$;

2) $N \cap E = \emptyset$;

3) $M \cup N = B_r(\textbf{0})$; and

4) $\forall \textbf{m} \in M, -\textbf{m} \notin int(M)$.

PROOF:

Assume for a contradiction that two such subset do not exist. Fix $r>0$ and let $L=B_r(\textbf{0}) \cap E$ and $K=B_r(\textbf{0})-L$. Clearly $L$ and $K$ satisfy the first three criteria. Hence, there must exist an $\ell \in L$ such that $-\ell \in int(L)$.

Remark: $K \neq \emptyset$ by assumption since $\textbf{0} \in \partial E$.

Since $- \ell \in int(L)$, there exists an open ball of radius $\epsilon > 0$ centered at $-\ell$ (henceforth $B_{\epsilon}(-\ell)$) such that $B_{\epsilon}(-\ell) \subset L$. Since $E$ is convex, $B_{\epsilon}(-\ell) \subset E$, and $\ell   \in E$, for all $\textbf{b} \in B_{\epsilon}(-\ell)$ and for all $t$ such that  $0<t<1$, $[\textbf{b}+t(\ell-\textbf{b})] \in E$. But since there is a bijection,  $f : B_{\epsilon}(\textbf{0}) \to B_{\epsilon}(-\ell)$, where $f(\textbf{x})=\textbf{x}-\ell$ (this follows trivially from the definition of balls), every $\textbf{b}$ can be uniquely written as $\textbf{b}=\pmb{ \epsilon}-\ell$, where $\pmb{\epsilon} \in B_{\epsilon}(\textbf{0})$. From this, we know that for all $\pmb{\epsilon} \in B_{\epsilon}(\textbf{0})$ and for all $t$ such that $0<t<1$, $[\pmb{\epsilon}-\ell+t(2\ell-\pmb{\epsilon}]\in E$. If we let $t=\frac{1}{2}$, we find that $B_{\epsilon/2}(\textbf{0}) \subset E$, a contradiction, since $\textbf{0} \in \partial E$.

Using the above Lemma, we see that if we set $r$ to be sufficiently large that $E \subset B_r(\textbf{0})$, then for all $\textbf{e} \in E$, $-\textbf{e} \notin int(E)$. This is where I get stuck. As you may have already guessed, I am trying to use linear algebra to prove this proposition and have gotten stuck. SOS!

Comment: In the proof of the lemma, I think you only get $B_{\epsilon/2}\subset E$. Further (after the lemma), why should there exist some r with $E\subset B_r(0)$? You are not assuming $E$ to be bounded!

Comment: Indeed, I meant $\epsilon/2$, thank you for catching that! Can we not just let $r \to \infty$ so that $B_r(\textbf{0})=\mathbb{R}^n$? Or is this not kosher?